# Красная метка в очереди, при этом очередь пуста

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

Возможно, дубликат. Вижу "красную метку" в очереди сообщений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при этом в очереди - пусто, нет сообщений на проверку. Что это - я накосячил или глюк?

Comment: [Будликат](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301576/339911)